# Why is jedi installed?

Tags: jupyter-lab, language-server-protocol, python-language-server, python-lsp-server, jupyterlab-lsp

My basic understanding is that [jedi](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) was an old method to do autocompletion / hints.

The new method is [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol), and we can use an LSP server with [jupyterlab](https://jupyter.org/install#jupyterlab) through [jupyterlab-lsp](https://jupyterlab-lsp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

One such LSP server for Python is [python-lsp-server](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server).

There is also a [jedi-language-server](https://github.com/pappasam/jedi-language-server) that, as my understanding goes, is a layer that exposes a LSP interface to jedi (the old method).

Now I want to use python-lsp-server.

I use pyenv to manage my virtual environments.

I do:

```
# This creates a Python 3.12 virtual environment
$ pyenv virtualenv 3.12.0 nojedi

# Basically this activates the environment
$ pyenv local nojedi

# Install packages
$ python -m jupyterlab jupyterlab-lsp "python-lsp-server[all]"
```

Then:

```
$ python -m pip list | grep jedi
jedi                      0.19.1
```

Why is jedi installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python-lsp-server [depends on Jedi](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server/blob/3525e8bd4dba5ab935060e26092cae3c9075588a/pyproject.toml#L18).

From its [README](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server#installation):

> The base language server requires Jedi to provide Completions, Definitions, Hover, References, Signature Help, and Symbols:

The only “obsolete” thing about Jedi when it comes to text editors is having its own API. It didn’t stop being good at Python static analysis.

Comment: What's he difference between `python-lsp-server` and `jedi-language-server`?

Comment: @robertspierre: That answer is also in a README: jedi-language-server’s.

Comment: I don't find it. [python-lsp-server](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server)'s README don't talk about jedi-language-server, and [jedi-language-server](https://github.com/pappasam/jedi-language-server)'s README don't talk about python-lsp-server.

Comment: @robertspierre: Compared to the fork base of python-lsp-server, rather: https://github.com/pappasam/jedi-language-server#inspiration

Comment: The paragraph you cited talk about [python-language-server](https://github.com/palantir/python-language-server). We are talking about [python-lsp-server](https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server)

Comment: @robertspierre: As I said, compared to the fork base of python-lsp-server, python-language-server. Same points apply.